# How to communicate webapp and web service running on tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, web-applications

I have a web application and web service(apache cxf) sharing same database and running on their own servlets.And i have foo class  with a field 'startdate' .I am tracing closest start date and schedule quart's simple  trigger to start at this date.But data also come from web service and i am cannot trace closest date .I can duplicate logic to web service and trace closest date separately but this lead resource leak .İs there a way inform webapp from web service .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Http-get  with parameter  to web app.

```
String queryString = "param1=" +
  URLEncoder.encode(param1Value, "UTF-8");
queryString += "&param2=" +
   URLEncoder.encode(param2Value, "UTF-8");

// Make connection

URL url = new URL("http://www.localhost.8080/");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
```